# Django forms. Create instance of foreign key on the fly.

Tags: python, django, forms, widget, foreign-keys

I have two classes, one of which has the other as a ForeignKey. The first class is DeliveryLocation, and the second class is Purchase. DeliveryLocation has two variables, city and zip. I want to make a form for Purchase, where the user can select the DeliveryLocation if its already been used, but can enter his/her own if it never has. Essentially I want to imitate the Admin sites "+" button to create a new DeliveryLocation from within the Purchase form.

I have found several pages that seem to be about the same thing, but no real answers. Thanks for any help, and let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Why this kind of question here?

Comment: Chances are, the DeliveryLocation will later grow to include more fields (like PersonToContact, PhoneNumber, etc.)  Create another form to add a DeliveryLocation's fields.  Then add a link to this form (like the "+" button) from the Purchase form, and back again.

Comment: Thanks @BrentWashburne. It's not exactly what I wanted, but will work (at least for now).